# Hiding Password in Shell Scripts

Tags: shell-script, security, password

How can I hide a password in shell scripts? There are a number of scripts that are accessing database. If we open the script others also aware the username and password. So if anyone knows how to hide please let me know.

I have one way: place the password in a file and make the file as hidden and no one going to access the file (change the permissions and use the file in script while going to accessing database).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**First**, as several people have already said, keeping the credentials separate from the script is essential. (In addition to increased security, it also means that you can re-use the same script for several systems with different credentials.)

**Second**, you should consider not only the security of the credentials but also the impact if/when those credentials are compromised. You shouldn't have just one password for all access to the database, you should have different credentials with different levels of access. You could, for instance, have one DB user that has the ability to perform a search in the database - that user should have read-only access. Another user may have permission to insert new records, but not to delete them. A third one may have permission to delete records.

In addition to restricting the permissions for each account, you should also have restriction on where each account can be used from. For instance, the account used by your web server should not be allowed to connect from any other IP address than that of the webserver. An account with full root permissions to the database should be very restricted indeed in terms of where it may connect from and should never be used other than interactively. Also, consider using stored procedures in the database to restrict exactly what can be done by each account.

These restrictions need to be implemented on the DB-server side of the system so that even if the client-side is compromised, the restrictions cannot be altered from it. (And, obviously, the DB server needs to be protected with firewalls etc in addition to the DB configuration...)

In the case of a DB account that is only permitted limited read-only access, and only from a particular IP address, you might not need any further credentials than that, depending on the sensitivity of the data and the security of the host the script is being run from. One example may be a search form on your web site, which can be run with a user that is only allowed to use a stored procedure which extracts only the information that will be presented on the web page. In this case, adding a password does not really confer any extra security, since that information is already meant to be public, and the user can't access any other data that would be more sensitive.

Also, make sure that the connection to the database is made using TLS, or anybody listening on the network can get your credentials.

**Third**, consider what kind of credentials to use. Passwords are just one form, and not the most secure. You could instead use some form of public/private key pair, or AD/PAM or the like.

**Fourth**, consider the conditions under which the script will be run:

If it is run interactively, then you should enter the password, or the password to the private key, or the private key, or be logged in with a valid Kerberos ticket, when you run it - in other words, the script should get its credentials directly from you at the time that you run it, instead of reading them from some file.

If it is run from a webserver, consider setting up the credentials at the time when you start the webserver. A good example here is SSL certificates - they have a public certificate and a private key, and the private key has a password. You may store the private key on the web server, but you still need to enter the password to it when you start Apache. You could also have the credentials on some kind of hardware, such as a physical card or an HSM, that can be removed or locked once the server is started. (Of course, the downside to this method is that the server can't restart on its own if something happens. I would prefer this to the risk of having my system compromised, but your mileage may vary...)

If the script is being run from cron, this is the hard part. You don't want to have the credentials lying around anywhere on your system where someone can access them - but you do want to have them lying around so that your script can access them, right? Well, not quite right. Consider exactly what the script is doing. What permissions does it need on the database? Can it be restricted so that it doesn't matter if the wrong person connects with those permissions? Can you instead run the script directly on the DB server that nobody else has access to, instead of from the server that does have other users? If, for some reason that I can't think of, you absolutely *must* have the script running on an insecure server and it *must* be able to do something dangerous/destructive... now is a good time to re-think your architecture.

**Fifth**, if you value the security of your database, you should not be running these scripts on servers that other people have access to. If someone is logged in on your system, then they **will** have the possibility to get at your credentials. For instance, in the case of a web server with an SSL certificate, there is at least a theoretical possibility of someone being able to gain root and access the httpd process's memory area and extract the credentials. There has been at least one exploit in recent times where this could be done over SSL, not even requiring the attacker to be logged in.

Also, consider using SELinux or AppArmor or whatever is available for your system to restrict which users can do what. They will make it possible for you to disallow users to even try to connect to the database, even if they do manage to gain access to the credentials.

**If all this sounds like overkill to you**, and you can't afford or don't have the time to do it - then, in my (arrogant and elitist) opinion, you should not be storing anything important or sensitive in your database. And if you're not storing anything important or sensitive, then where you store your credentials is also not important - in which case, why use a password at all?

**Lastly**, if you absolutely cannot avoid storing some kind of credentials, you could have the credentials read-only and own by root and root could grant ownership on an exceedingly temporary basis when requested to do so by a script (because your script should **not** be run as root unless absolutely necessary, and connecting to a database does not make it necessary). But it's still not a good idea.

Comment: Not arrogant and elitist at all.  Or else I am, too.  "How can I protect my jewelry in case a burglar breaks in?"  "Put it in a safe that is bolted/welded in place."  "That's too much trouble, I'll just get a portable safe and hang the key from a hook."  "Then don't bother using a safe."  Eminently sensible advice.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, if there is any way at all you can change things to avoid having to store a password inside or alongside a script in the first place, you should make every effort to do that. [Jenny D's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/hiding-password-in-shell-scripts/212363#212363) contains a lot of good advice to that effect.

Otherwise, your idea of placing the password in a separate file with restricted permissions is pretty much it. You can for example source that file from the main script:

```
. /usr/local/etc/secret-password-here
```

You could also restrict the permissions of the main script so that only authorized persons can execute it, but it's probably better to do as you suggest and store only the password itself in a restricted file. That way you can allow inspection of the code itself (without sensitive secrets), version-control and copy around the script more easily, etc...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ah but I see that it also says "`/usr/local/etc` may be a symbolic link to `/etc/local`". I missed that. So you're also right, but it's a MAY so it's optional. But yeah, it doesn't matter much, and personal preference.

Comment: Except that I am backuping `/etc/`  but not `/usr/local/`  (which I assume can be rebuilt after disk crash)

Comment: fair point about backups

Comment: A complete example script with above file usage would be helpful for layman

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, without regard to security (I also think it is better to keep the credentials in another file or in a database) is to encrypt the password with gpg and insert it in the script.

> I use a password-less gpg key pair that I keep in a usb. (Note: When you export this key pair don't use --armor, export them in binary format).

First encrypt your password:

```
echo -n "pAssw0rd" | gpg --armor --no-default-keyring --keyring /media/usb/key.pub --recipient someone@mail.com --encrypt
```

That will be print out the gpg encrypted password in the standart output. Copy the whole message and add this to the script:

```
password=$(gpg --batch --quiet --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /media/usb/key.priv --decrypt <<EOF 
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hQEMA0CjbyauRLJ8AQgAkZT5gK8TrdH6cZEy+Ufl0PObGZJ1YEbshacZb88RlRB9
h2z+s/Bso5HQxNd5tzkwulvhmoGu6K6hpMXM3mbYl07jHF4qr+oWijDkdjHBVcn5
0mkpYO1riUf0HXIYnvCZq/4k/ajGZRm8EdDy2JIWuwiidQ18irp07UUNO+AB9mq8
5VXUjUN3tLTexg4sLZDKFYGRi4fyVrYKGsi0i5AEHKwn5SmTb3f1pa5yXbv68eYE
lCVfy51rBbG87UTycZ3gFQjf1UkNVbp0WV+RPEM9JR7dgR+9I8bKCuKLFLnGaqvc
beA3A6eMpzXQqsAg6GGo3PW6fMHqe1ZCvidi6e4a/dJDAbHq0XWp93qcwygnWeQW
Ozr1hr5mCa+QkUSymxiUrRncRhyqSP0ok5j4rjwSJu9vmHTEUapiyQMQaEIF2e2S
/NIWGg==
=uriR
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
EOF)
```

In this way only if the usb is mounted in the system the password can be decrypted. Of course you can also import the keys into the system (less secure, or no security at all) or you can protect the private key with password (so it can not be automated).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have addressed the *how*, but I'll consider the *whether*.  Depending on what kind of database your users are connecting to, you might already have a suitable mechanism that's already used by those client programs, in which case be sure to use them (I'm thinking of `~/.mysqlrc` or `~/.pgpass`).

If you're giving several users the ability to access the database to make specific queries using a shared account, then you probably shouldn't.  Instead, make sure they have accounts on the database and that those accounts have no more permissions than they need (probably read on much of it, and very little write access).  If they need to make specific queries on certain tables that they can't otherwise access, provide stored procedures with `SECURTY DEFINER` to allow them to do so.

If none of the above avoids you needing to store credentials, *then* read the other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well.  The short answer is to store the password separate from the script and then have the script load in the password from the environment.  Which raises the question how best to do that?

Ideally you might use an external service like HashiCorp Vault to pull it into the shell environment; however, Vault is a fairly complicated beast to setup and in many enterprise environments you might be limited by what you can install and even what type of shell you might be able to use.

For this reason, I created [encpass.sh - Lightweight solution for using encrypted passwords in shell scripts](https://github.com/plyint/encpass.sh) that allows you store secrets in a hidden directory only accessible by your user.  It should work in any POSIX compliant shell and it's only real dependency is having OpenSSL installed on the local box to handle the encryption of secrets.  All you have to do is include it in your script and call the "get_secret" function.  It has an MIT License, so you can use it in a corporate environment. My company, [Plyint LLC](https://plyint.com), maintains the script and releases updates occasionally.  I'll copy the code below for easy visibility.

```
#!/bin/sh
################################################################################
# Copyright (c) 2020 Plyint, LLC <contact@plyint.com>. All Rights Reserved.
# This file is licensed under the MIT License (MIT). 
# Please see LICENSE.txt for more information.
# 
# DESCRIPTION: 
# This script allows a user to encrypt a password (or any other secret) at 
# runtime and then use it, decrypted, within a script.  This prevents shoulder 
# surfing passwords and avoids storing the password in plain text, which could 
# inadvertently be sent to or discovered by an individual at a later date.
#
# This script generates an AES 256 bit symmetric key for each script (or user-
# defined bucket) that stores secrets.  This key will then be used to encrypt 
# all secrets for that script or bucket.  encpass.sh sets up a directory 
# (.encpass) under the user's home directory where keys and secrets will be 
# stored.
#
# For further details, see README.md or run "./encpass ?" from the command line.
#
################################################################################

encpass_checks() {
    if [ -n "$ENCPASS_CHECKS" ]; then
        return
    fi

    if [ ! -x "$(command -v openssl)" ]; then
        echo "Error: OpenSSL is not installed or not accessible in the current path." \
            "Please install it and try again." >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ -z "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR" ]; then
        ENCPASS_HOME_DIR=$(encpass_get_abs_filename ~)/.encpass
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR" ]; then
        mkdir -m 700 "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR"
        mkdir -m 700 "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys"
        mkdir -m 700 "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets"
    fi

    if [ "$(basename "$0")" != "encpass.sh" ]; then
        encpass_include_init "$1" "$2"
    fi

    ENCPASS_CHECKS=1
}

# Initializations performed when the script is included by another script
encpass_include_init() {
    if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]; then
        ENCPASS_BUCKET=$1
        ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME=$2
    elif [ -n "$1" ]; then
        ENCPASS_BUCKET=$(basename "$0")
        ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME=$1
    else
        ENCPASS_BUCKET=$(basename "$0")
        ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME="password"
    fi
}

encpass_generate_private_key() {
    ENCPASS_KEY_DIR="$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/$ENCPASS_BUCKET"

    if [ ! -d "$ENCPASS_KEY_DIR" ]; then
        mkdir -m 700 "$ENCPASS_KEY_DIR"
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_DIR/private.key" ]; then
        (umask 0377 && printf "%s" "$(openssl rand -hex 32)" >"$ENCPASS_KEY_DIR/private.key")
    fi
}

encpass_get_private_key_abs_name() {
    ENCPASS_PRIVATE_KEY_ABS_NAME="$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/$ENCPASS_BUCKET/private.key"

    if [ "$1" != "nogenerate" ]; then 
        if [ ! -f "$ENCPASS_PRIVATE_KEY_ABS_NAME" ]; then
            encpass_generate_private_key
        fi
    fi
}

encpass_get_secret_abs_name() {
    ENCPASS_SECRET_ABS_NAME="$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/$ENCPASS_BUCKET/$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME.enc"

    if [ "$3" != "nocreate" ]; then 
        if [ ! -f "$ENCPASS_SECRET_ABS_NAME" ]; then
            set_secret "$1" "$2"
        fi
    fi
}

get_secret() {
    encpass_checks "$1" "$2"
    encpass_get_private_key_abs_name
    encpass_get_secret_abs_name "$1" "$2"
    encpass_decrypt_secret
}

set_secret() {
    encpass_checks "$1" "$2"

    if [ "$3" != "reuse" ] || { [ -z "$ENCPASS_SECRET_INPUT" ] && [ -z "$ENCPASS_CSECRET_INPUT" ]; }; then
        echo "Enter $ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME:" >&2
        stty -echo
        read -r ENCPASS_SECRET_INPUT
        stty echo
        echo "Confirm $ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME:" >&2
        stty -echo
        read -r ENCPASS_CSECRET_INPUT
        stty echo
    fi

    if [ "$ENCPASS_SECRET_INPUT" = "$ENCPASS_CSECRET_INPUT" ]; then
        encpass_get_private_key_abs_name
        ENCPASS_SECRET_DIR="$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/$ENCPASS_BUCKET"

        if [ ! -d "$ENCPASS_SECRET_DIR" ]; then
            mkdir -m 700 "$ENCPASS_SECRET_DIR"
        fi

        printf "%s" "$(openssl rand -hex 16)" >"$ENCPASS_SECRET_DIR/$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME.enc"

        ENCPASS_OPENSSL_IV="$(cat "$ENCPASS_SECRET_DIR/$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME.enc")"

        echo "$ENCPASS_SECRET_INPUT" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -a -iv \
            "$ENCPASS_OPENSSL_IV" -K \
            "$(cat "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/$ENCPASS_BUCKET/private.key")" 1>> \
                    "$ENCPASS_SECRET_DIR/$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME.enc"
    else
        echo "Error: secrets do not match.  Please try again." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
}

encpass_get_abs_filename() {
    # $1 : relative filename
    filename="$1"
    parentdir="$(dirname "${filename}")"

    if [ -d "${filename}" ]; then
        cd "${filename}" && pwd
    elif [ -d "${parentdir}" ]; then
        echo "$(cd "${parentdir}" && pwd)/$(basename "${filename}")"
    fi
}

encpass_decrypt_secret() {
    if [ -f "$ENCPASS_PRIVATE_KEY_ABS_NAME" ]; then
        ENCPASS_DECRYPT_RESULT="$(dd if="$ENCPASS_SECRET_ABS_NAME" ibs=1 skip=32 2> /dev/null | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc \
            -d -a -iv "$(head -c 32 "$ENCPASS_SECRET_ABS_NAME")" -K "$(cat "$ENCPASS_PRIVATE_KEY_ABS_NAME")" 2> /dev/null)"
        if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_DECRYPT_RESULT" ]; then
            echo "$ENCPASS_DECRYPT_RESULT"
        else
            # If a failed unlock command occurred and the user tries to show the secret
            # Present either locked or decrypt command
            if [ -f "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/$ENCPASS_BUCKET/private.lock" ]; then 
            echo "**Locked**"
            else
                # The locked file wasn't present as expected.  Let's display a failure
            echo "Error: Failed to decrypt"
            fi
        fi
    elif [ -f "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/$ENCPASS_BUCKET/private.lock" ]; then
        echo "**Locked**"
    else
        echo "Error: Unable to decrypt. The key file \"$ENCPASS_PRIVATE_KEY_ABS_NAME\" is not present."
    fi
}


##########################################################
# COMMAND LINE MANAGEMENT SUPPORT
# -------------------------------
# If you don't need to manage the secrets for the scripts
# with encpass.sh you can delete all code below this point
# in order to significantly reduce the size of encpass.sh.
# This is useful if you want to bundle encpass.sh with
# your existing scripts and just need the retrieval
# functions.
##########################################################

encpass_show_secret() {
    encpass_checks
    ENCPASS_BUCKET=$1

    encpass_get_private_key_abs_name "nogenerate"

    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME=$2
        encpass_get_secret_abs_name "$1" "$2" "nocreate"
        if [ -z "$ENCPASS_SECRET_ABS_NAME" ]; then
            echo "No secret named $2 found for bucket $1."
            exit 1
        fi

        encpass_decrypt_secret
    else
        ENCPASS_FILE_LIST=$(ls -1 "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR"/secrets/"$1")
        for ENCPASS_F in $ENCPASS_FILE_LIST; do
            ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME=$(basename "$ENCPASS_F" .enc)

            encpass_get_secret_abs_name "$1" "$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME" "nocreate"
            if [ -z "$ENCPASS_SECRET_ABS_NAME" ]; then
                echo "No secret named $ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME found for bucket $1."
                exit 1
            fi

            echo "$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME = $(encpass_decrypt_secret)"
        done
    fi
}

encpass_getche() {
        old=$(stty -g)
        stty raw min 1 time 0
        printf '%s' "$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)"
        stty "$old"
}

encpass_remove() {
    if [ ! -n "$ENCPASS_FORCE_REMOVE" ]; then
        if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_SECRET" ]; then
            printf "Are you sure you want to remove the secret \"%s\" from bucket \"%s\"? [y/N]" "$ENCPASS_SECRET" "$ENCPASS_BUCKET"
        else
            printf "Are you sure you want to remove the bucket \"%s?\" [y/N]" "$ENCPASS_BUCKET"
        fi

        ENCPASS_CONFIRM="$(encpass_getche)"
        printf "\n"
        if [ "$ENCPASS_CONFIRM" != "Y" ] && [ "$ENCPASS_CONFIRM" != "y" ]; then
            exit 0
        fi
    fi

    if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_SECRET" ]; then
        rm -f "$1"
        printf "Secret \"%s\" removed from bucket \"%s\".\n" "$ENCPASS_SECRET" "$ENCPASS_BUCKET"
    else
        rm -Rf "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/$ENCPASS_BUCKET"
        rm -Rf "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/$ENCPASS_BUCKET"
        printf "Bucket \"%s\" removed.\n" "$ENCPASS_BUCKET"
    fi
}

encpass_save_err() {
    if read -r x; then
        { printf "%s\n" "$x"; cat; } > "$1"
    elif [ "$x" != "" ]; then
        printf "%s" "$x" > "$1"
    fi
}

encpass_help() {
less << EOF
NAME:
    encpass.sh - Use encrypted passwords in shell scripts

DESCRIPTION: 
    A lightweight solution for using encrypted passwords in shell scripts 
    using OpenSSL. It allows a user to encrypt a password (or any other secret)
    at runtime and then use it, decrypted, within a script. This prevents
    shoulder surfing passwords and avoids storing the password in plain text, 
    within a script, which could inadvertently be sent to or discovered by an 
    individual at a later date.

    This script generates an AES 256 bit symmetric key for each script 
    (or user-defined bucket) that stores secrets. This key will then be used 
    to encrypt all secrets for that script or bucket.

    Subsequent calls to retrieve a secret will not prompt for a secret to be 
    entered as the file with the encrypted value already exists.

    Note: By default, encpass.sh sets up a directory (.encpass) under the 
    user's home directory where keys and secrets will be stored.  This directory
    can be overridden by setting the environment variable ENCPASS_HOME_DIR to a
    directory of your choice.

    ~/.encpass (or the directory specified by ENCPASS_HOME_DIR) will contain 
    the following subdirectories:
      - keys (Holds the private key for each script/bucket)
      - secrets (Holds the secrets stored for each script/bucket)

USAGE:
    To use the encpass.sh script in an existing shell script, source the script 
    and then call the get_secret function.

    Example:

        #!/bin/sh
        . encpass.sh
        password=\$(get_secret)

    When no arguments are passed to the get_secret function,
    then the bucket name is set to the name of the script and
    the secret name is set to "password".

    There are 2 other ways to call get_secret:

      Specify the secret name:
      Ex: \$(get_secret user)
        - bucket name = <script name>
        - secret name = "user"

      Specify both the secret name and bucket name:
      Ex: \$(get_secret personal user)
        - bucket name = "personal"
        - secret name = "user"

    encpass.sh also provides a command line interface to manage the secrets.
    To invoke a command, pass it as an argument to encpass.sh from the shell.

        $ encpass.sh [COMMAND]

    See the COMMANDS section below for a list of available commands.  Wildcard
    handling is implemented for secret and bucket names.  This enables
    performing operations like adding/removing a secret to/from multiple buckets
        at once.

COMMANDS:
    add [-f] <bucket> <secret>
        Add a secret to the specified bucket.  The bucket will be created
        if it does not already exist. If a secret with the same name already
        exists for the specified bucket, then the user will be prompted to
        confirm overwriting the value.  If the -f option is passed, then the
        add operation will perform a forceful overwrite of the value. (i.e. no
        prompt)

    list|ls [<bucket>]
        Display the names of the secrets held in the bucket.  If no bucket
        is specified, then the names of all existing buckets will be
        displayed.

    lock
        Locks all keys used by encpass.sh using a password.  The user
        will be prompted to enter a password and confirm it.  A user
        should take care to securely store the password.  If the password
        is lost then keys can not be unlocked.  When keys are locked,
        secrets can not be retrieved. (e.g. the output of the values
        in the "show" command will be encrypted/garbage)

    remove|rm [-f] <bucket> [<secret>]
        Remove a secret from the specified bucket.  If only a bucket is
        specified then the entire bucket (i.e. all secrets and keys) will
        be removed.  By default the user is asked to confirm the removal of
        the secret or the bucket.  If the -f option is passed then a 
        forceful removal will be performed.  (i.e. no prompt)

    show [<bucket>] [<secret>]
        Show the unencrypted value of the secret from the specified bucket.
        If no secret is specified then all secrets for the bucket are displayed.

    update <bucket> <secret>
        Updates a secret in the specified bucket.  This command is similar
        to using an "add -f" command, but it has a safety check to only 
        proceed if the specified secret exists.  If the secret, does not
        already exist, then an error will be reported. There is no forceable
        update implemented.  Use "add -f" for any required forceable update
        scenarios.

    unlock
        Unlocks all the keys for encpass.sh.  The user will be prompted to 
        enter the password and confirm it.

    dir
        Prints out the current value of the ENCPASS_HOME_DIR environment variable.

    help|--help|usage|--usage|?
        Display this help message.
EOF
}

# Subcommands for cli support
case "$1" in
    add )
        shift
        while getopts ":f" ENCPASS_OPTS; do
            case "$ENCPASS_OPTS" in
                f ) ENCPASS_FORCE_ADD=1;;
            esac
        done

        encpass_checks

        if [ -n "$ENCPASS_FORCE_ADD" ]; then
            shift $((OPTIND-1))
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$1" ] && [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
            # Allow globbing
            # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
            ENCPASS_ADD_LIST="$(ls -1d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$1"" 2>/dev/null)"
            if [ -z "$ENCPASS_ADD_LIST" ]; then
                ENCPASS_ADD_LIST="$1"
            fi

            for ENCPASS_ADD_F in $ENCPASS_ADD_LIST; do
                ENCPASS_ADD_DIR="$(basename "$ENCPASS_ADD_F")"
                ENCPASS_BUCKET="$ENCPASS_ADD_DIR"
                if [ ! -n "$ENCPASS_FORCE_ADD" ] && [ -f "$ENCPASS_ADD_F/$2.enc" ]; then
                    echo "Warning: A secret with the name \"$2\" already exists for bucket $ENCPASS_BUCKET."
                    echo "Would you like to overwrite the value? [y/N]"

                    ENCPASS_CONFIRM="$(encpass_getche)"
                    if [ "$ENCPASS_CONFIRM" != "Y" ] && [ "$ENCPASS_CONFIRM" != "y" ]; then
                        continue
                    fi
                fi

                ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME="$2"
                echo "Adding secret \"$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME\" to bucket \"$ENCPASS_BUCKET\"..."
                set_secret "$ENCPASS_BUCKET" "$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME" "reuse"
            done
        else
            echo "Error: A bucket name and secret name must be provided when adding a secret."
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    update )
        shift

        encpass_checks
        if [ ! -z "$1" ] && [ ! -z "$2" ]; then

            ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME="$2"
            # Allow globbing
            # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
            ENCPASS_UPDATE_LIST="$(ls -1d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$1"" 2>/dev/null)"

            for ENCPASS_UPDATE_F in $ENCPASS_UPDATE_LIST; do
                # Allow globbing
                # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
                if [ -f "$ENCPASS_UPDATE_F/"$2".enc" ]; then
                        ENCPASS_UPDATE_DIR="$(basename "$ENCPASS_UPDATE_F")"
                        ENCPASS_BUCKET="$ENCPASS_UPDATE_DIR"
                        echo "Updating secret \"$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME\" to bucket \"$ENCPASS_BUCKET\"..."
                        set_secret "$ENCPASS_BUCKET" "$ENCPASS_SECRET_NAME" "reuse"
                else
                    echo "Error: A secret with the name \"$2\" does not exist for bucket $1."
                    exit 1
                fi
            done
        else
            echo "Error: A bucket name and secret name must be provided when updating a secret."
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    rm|remove )
        shift
        encpass_checks

        while getopts ":f" ENCPASS_OPTS; do
            case "$ENCPASS_OPTS" in
                f ) ENCPASS_FORCE_REMOVE=1;;
            esac
        done

        if [ -n "$ENCPASS_FORCE_REMOVE" ]; then
            shift $((OPTIND-1))
        fi

        if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
            echo "Error: A bucket must be specified for removal."
        fi

        # Allow globbing
        # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
        ENCPASS_REMOVE_BKT_LIST="$(ls -1d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$1"" 2>/dev/null)"
        if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_REMOVE_BKT_LIST" ]; then
            for ENCPASS_REMOVE_B in $ENCPASS_REMOVE_BKT_LIST; do

                ENCPASS_BUCKET="$(basename "$ENCPASS_REMOVE_B")"
                if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
                    # Removing secrets for a specified bucket
                    # Allow globbing
                    # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
                    ENCPASS_REMOVE_LIST="$(ls -1p "$ENCPASS_REMOVE_B/"$2".enc" 2>/dev/null)"

                    if [ -z "$ENCPASS_REMOVE_LIST" ]; then
                        echo "Error: No secrets found for $2 in bucket $ENCPASS_BUCKET."
                        exit 1
                    fi

                    for ENCPASS_REMOVE_F in $ENCPASS_REMOVE_LIST; do
                        ENCPASS_SECRET="$2"
                        encpass_remove "$ENCPASS_REMOVE_F"
                    done
                else
                    # Removing a specified bucket
                    encpass_remove
                fi

            done
        else
            echo "Error: The bucket named $1 does not exist."
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    show )
        shift
        encpass_checks
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
            ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR="*"
        else
            ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR=$1
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
            # Allow globbing
            # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
            if [ -f "$(encpass_get_abs_filename "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/$ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR/"$2".enc")" ]; then
                encpass_show_secret "$ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR" "$2"
            fi
        else
            # Allow globbing
            # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
            ENCPASS_SHOW_LIST="$(ls -1d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR"" 2>/dev/null)"

            if [ -z "$ENCPASS_SHOW_LIST" ]; then
                if [ "$ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR" = "*" ]; then
                    echo "Error: No buckets exist."
                else
                    echo "Error: Bucket $1 does not exist."
                fi
                exit 1
            fi

            for ENCPASS_SHOW_F in $ENCPASS_SHOW_LIST; do
                ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR="$(basename "$ENCPASS_SHOW_F")"
                echo "$ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR:"
                encpass_show_secret "$ENCPASS_SHOW_DIR"
                echo " "
            done
        fi
        ;;
    ls|list )
        shift
        encpass_checks
        if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
            # Allow globbing
            # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
            ENCPASS_FILE_LIST="$(ls -1p "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$1"" 2>/dev/null)"

            if [ -z "$ENCPASS_FILE_LIST" ]; then
                # Allow globbing
                # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
                ENCPASS_DIR_EXISTS="$(ls -d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$1"" 2>/dev/null)"
                if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_DIR_EXISTS" ]; then
                    echo "Bucket $1 is empty."
                else
                    echo "Error: Bucket $1 does not exist."
                fi
                exit 1
            fi

            ENCPASS_NL=""
            for ENCPASS_F in $ENCPASS_FILE_LIST; do
                if [ -d "${ENCPASS_F%:}" ]; then
                    printf "$ENCPASS_NL%s\n" "$(basename "$ENCPASS_F")"
                    ENCPASS_NL="\n"
                else
                    printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$ENCPASS_F" .enc)"
                fi
            done
        else
            # Allow globbing
            # shellcheck disable=SC2027,SC2086
            ENCPASS_BUCKET_LIST="$(ls -1p "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/secrets/"$1"" 2>/dev/null)"
            for ENCPASS_C in $ENCPASS_BUCKET_LIST; do
                if [ -d "${ENCPASS_C%:}" ]; then
                    printf "\n%s" "\n$(basename "$ENCPASS_C")"
                else
                    basename "$ENCPASS_C" .enc
                fi
            done
        fi
        ;;
    lock )
        shift
        encpass_checks

        echo "************************!!!WARNING!!!*************************" >&2
        echo "* You are about to lock your keys with a password.           *" >&2
        echo "* You will not be able to use your secrets again until you   *" >&2
        echo "* unlock the keys with the same password. It is important    *" >&2
        echo "* that you securely store the password, so you can recall it *" >&2
        echo "* in the future.  If you forget your password you will no    *" >&2
        echo "* longer be able to access your secrets.                     *" >&2
        echo "************************!!!WARNING!!!*************************" >&2

        printf "\n%s\n" "About to lock keys held in directory $ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/"

        printf "\nEnter Password to lock keys:" >&2
        stty -echo
        read -r ENCPASS_KEY_PASS
        printf "\nConfirm Password:" >&2
        read -r ENCPASS_CKEY_PASS
        printf "\n"
        stty echo

        if [ -z "$ENCPASS_KEY_PASS" ]; then
            echo "Error: You must supply a password value."
            exit 1
        fi

        if [ "$ENCPASS_KEY_PASS" = "$ENCPASS_CKEY_PASS" ]; then
            ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_LOCKED=0
            ENCPASS_KEYS_LIST="$(ls -1d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/"*"/" 2>/dev/null)"
            for ENCPASS_KEY_F in $ENCPASS_KEYS_LIST; do

                if [ -d "${ENCPASS_KEY_F%:}" ]; then
                    ENCPASS_KEY_NAME="$(basename "$ENCPASS_KEY_F")"
                    ENCPASS_KEY_VALUE=""
                    if [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key" ]; then
                        ENCPASS_KEY_VALUE="$(cat "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key")"
                        if [ ! -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" ]; then
                        echo "Locking key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME..."
                        else
                          echo "Error: The key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME appears to have been previously locked."
                            echo "       The current key file may hold a bad value. Exiting to avoid encrypting"
                            echo "       a bad value and overwriting the lock file."
                            exit 1
                        fi
                    else
                        echo "Error: Private key file ${ENCPASS_KEY_F}private.key missing for bucket $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME."
                        exit 1
                    fi
                    if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_KEY_VALUE" ]; then
                        openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -salt -in "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key" -out "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" -k "$ENCPASS_KEY_PASS"
                        if [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key" ] && [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" ]; then
                            # Both the key and lock file exist.  We can remove the key file now
                            rm -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key"
                            echo "Locked key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME."
                            ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_LOCKED=$(( ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_LOCKED + 1 ))
                        else
                            echo "Error: The key fle and/or lock file were not found as expected for key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME."
                        fi
                    else
                        echo "Error: No key value found for the $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME key."
                        exit 1
                    fi
                fi
            done
            echo "Locked $ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_LOCKED keys."
        else
            echo "Error: Passwords do not match."
        fi
        ;;
    unlock )
        shift
        encpass_checks

        printf "%s\n" "About to unlock keys held in the $ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/ directory."

        printf "\nEnter Password to unlock keys: " >&2
        stty -echo
        read -r ENCPASS_KEY_PASS
        printf "\n"
        stty echo

        if [ ! -z "$ENCPASS_KEY_PASS" ]; then
            ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_UNLOCKED=0
            ENCPASS_KEYS_LIST="$(ls -1d "$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR/keys/"*"/" 2>/dev/null)"
            for ENCPASS_KEY_F in $ENCPASS_KEYS_LIST; do

                if [ -d "${ENCPASS_KEY_F%:}" ]; then
                    ENCPASS_KEY_NAME="$(basename "$ENCPASS_KEY_F")"
                    echo "Unlocking key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME..."
                    if [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key" ] && [ ! -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" ]; then
                        echo "Error: Key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME appears to be unlocked already."
                        exit 1
                    fi

                    if [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" ]; then
                        # Remove the failed file in case previous decryption attempts were unsuccessful
                        rm -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/failed" 2>/dev/null

                        # Decrypt key. Log any failure to the "failed" file.
                        openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -salt \
                            -in "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" -out "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key" \
                            -k "$ENCPASS_KEY_PASS" 2>&1 | encpass_save_err "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/failed"

                        if [ ! -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/failed" ]; then
                            # No failure has occurred.
                          if [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.key" ] && [ -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock" ]; then
                              # Both the key and lock file exist.  We can remove the lock file now.
                              rm -f "$ENCPASS_KEY_F/private.lock"
                              echo "Unlocked key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME."
                              ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_UNLOCKED=$(( ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_UNLOCKED + 1 ))
                          else
                              echo "Error: The key file and/or lock file were not found as expected for key $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME."
                          fi
                        else
                          printf "Error: Failed to unlock key %s.\n" "$ENCPASS_KEY_NAME"
                            printf "       Please view %sfailed for details.\n" "$ENCPASS_KEY_F"
                        fi
                    else
                        echo "Error: No lock file found for the $ENCPASS_KEY_NAME key."
                    fi
                fi
            done
            echo "Unlocked $ENCPASS_NUM_KEYS_UNLOCKED keys."
        else
            echo "No password entered."
        fi
        ;;
    dir )
        shift
        encpass_checks
        echo "ENCPASS_HOME_DIR=$ENCPASS_HOME_DIR"
        ;;
    help|--help|usage|--usage|\? )
        encpass_checks
        encpass_help
        ;;
    * )
        if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
            echo "Command not recognized. See \"encpass.sh help\" for a list commands."
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of hiding the password in an inaccessible place might be OK depending on the circumstances.

If the information is separate, that means simple editing of the file, e.g. during a code review with a colleague is not going to show it. But realise anyone with access to your account can easily find such a file. I have used a subdirectory of `~/.ssh` for such purposes, for the simple reason that `ssh` complains if the access rights for `~/.ssh` are not restricted enough.

There are however other things you can do to prevent such glancing of username and/or passwords.

**Obfuscating**:
If you don't want anyone to read the username or password while you edit a script you can put it in the text but not as plain text, but obfuscated. If the obfuscated version is long enough preventing its memorization by someone looking at it, it cannot be known even if the decryption method and key are in plain sight. This would of course still be trivially circumvented by someone having access to your account.

**Using GPG**:

Slightly better, but still not full proof against attacks by the root user on your system, is to encrypt username/password pairs in a file your `gpg` public and having the script retrieve the content on the file (possible prompting you for a password, if not cached/expired). I use ggp-card so that when I leave my laptop around but pull the card out, no access is possible even if the pin would still be cached. At least if I run thing 20 times in a few minutes I  have to provide the pin only once.

Security seems always inversely related to convenience (setting up and using).

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to store passwords in a bash script but you have to **encrypt and obfuscate the script** so that no one can actually read it or run any type of debugger on it to see exactly what it is doing. To encrypt and obfuscate a bash/shell script and have it actually be executable, try copying and pasting it here:

http://www.kinglazy.com/shell-script-encryption-kinglazy-shieldx.htm

On the above page, all you have to do is submit your script (you can submit a sample script first for your peace of mind). A zip file will be generated for you. Right click on the download link and copy the URL you're provided. Then, go to your UNIX box and perform the following steps.

**Installation:**

1. wget link-to-the-zip-file
2. unzip the-newly-downloaded-zip-file
3. cd /tmp/KingLazySHIELD
4. ./install.sh /var/tmp/KINGLAZY/SHIELDX-(your-script-name) /home/(your-username) -force

**What the above install command will do for you is:**

1. It'll install the encrypted version of your script in the directory /var/tmp/KINGLAZY/SHIELDX-(your-script-name).
2. It'll place a link to this encrypted script in whichever directory you specify in replacement of /home/(your-username) - that way, it allows you to easily access the script without having to type the absolute path.
3. Ensures NO ONE can modify the script - Any attempts to modify the encrypted script will render it inoperable...until those attempts are stopped or removed.  It can even be configured to notify you whenever someone tries to do anything with the script other than run it...i.e. hacking or modification attempts.
4. Ensures absolutely NO ONE can make copies of it. No one can copy your script to a secluded location and try to screw around with it to see how it works. All copies of the script must be links to the original location which you specified during install (step 4).

**NOTE:**

I don't believe this works for interactive scripts that prompts the user for a response. The values should be hard-coded into the script. The encryption ensures no one can actually see those values so you need not worry about that.

Comment: Is this a viable solution if the scripts are being versioned?

Comment: This answer is misleading and dangerous.
You are promoting "security by obscurity", your "solution" does not actually solve the problem but make people believe some magic happens. And you are promoting external products and services, aka SNAKEOIL.

Another read flag is that almost the same answer was added at several places in the stackexchange universum

Answer (score -8):

I don't believe you should ever store the password. I can't think of a single good reason for that. Rather, you should store a [salted hash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) of that password - some string which is produced reliably by some function when the original password is passed as input, but never *the password*.

Comment: I'm unclear on how this will solve the problem of a) being able to connect to a service requiring a password, and b) users being able to see the script and thus being able to figure out the authentication details, whether those are passwords or not

Comment: @JennyD - if you need to connect to a service - then you donit with a certificate of course. You do not put passwords in plain text. Period. I don't understand what you're talking about w/ `b`.

Comment: Sure, but again within the constraints of a shell script, anyone who can get at it can also get at the certificate...

Comment: @JennyD - of course they might. That's why we have public/private certs. This is not a new problem.

Comment: And then you have the problem of protecting the key - which, again, if you have access to the script, then you can get at the credentials, whether they be a password or a file. The problem isn't new, but that doesn't mean that it's easily solved for your average shell script writer.

Comment: @JennyD - No. The private key is yours. It doesn't go on the system w/ the script - it is not distributed. This is not a new problem. This is a common problem. The solution to this problem is certification. It needn't be done necessarily with a common GPG/SSL cert. Hardware can be certified - it happens all of the time. Users can be certified - and in fact it happens each time they login. If a shell scripter needs a password - the script needs to stop and ask for it or certify otherwise. You don't put passwords in scripts - ever - and you certainly don't recommend the *average scripter* should

Comment: Firstly, At no point did I recommend using passwords in scripts. Secondly, for a script that is run interactively, obviously entering the password or the key is trivial - the problem is when the scripts are **not** run interactively. I'd be very interested in your take on this in an answer.

Comment: @JennyD - I've given my answer - *never* do this. That's the only answer this question should ever have got. And yes, i know, you recommend a root-owned file. So how does the script read it exactly - it's root too? You don't run shell scripts as root either - not after init. They should be run as *nobody* - which might be an acceptable way to go if a pre-authorized proxy service runs in the background which can grant permissions based on predefined rules *(which is how this is usually done - such as w/ `PAM`)*. Compromised security is *not* a solution, but a problem.

Comment: Your predictive powers are lacking.

Comment: @JennyD Im not predicting anything. Ok *restricted permissions* which is better - but you still don't store passwords. Who does that? Is there any robust solution which you can name which does that?

Comment: You are claiming to know my answer before I've written it.

Comment: It would have been really interesting to get to read an actual answer that the poster could have used to implement a more secure system from you. Do you think you might write one at some point?

Comment: @JennyD - i thought you had answered here! Well, now im curious. I guess i was predicting. In any case the real answer is flatly - don't. That's mine, anyhow - but it's real enough.

Comment: I've written my answer now. What I was trying to get at from you was partly my fifth point - once the credentials are stored in memory they are not fully secure from an attacker with access to the server. Also that your terse answer was not very helpful, even though not incorrect. I'm thinking of pointing at it the next time someone complains that we at ServerFault are not as nice as the people at Unix/Linux :-)

Comment: @JennyD - once the cred is in memory - it certainly doesn't need to stay there - and that's a very good reason to deal w/ hashes instead anyway. Still, i'll happily represent community's courtesy standards as its exemplar at large - im very well known for that trait, in fact.

Comment: We agree on a lot here - thanks for doing that - you did it very well. I still think the user should have been told directly and flatly *no* - any db worth its salt already provides some remote access solution and will doc it. And i'll leave this answer - though i would normally delete it if i believed a far better answer in the same vein had made *(as i do now)*, for you and your SF friends. I would not wish to be discourteous.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! If this had been ServerFault I would have voted to close it for not being according to business practices... but here I'm more willing to take the time to educate people being new to things.

Comment: After your big discussion I would just like to mention in case there's any misunderstanding that it was I who downvoted, not Jenny. And the reason wasn't an opinion on whether or not it's a good idea to use a certificate&privkey or interactively-entered password or do what the OP wanted or whatever. It was because the answer as it stands is wrong: storing a salted hash of the password as a client credential isn't a thing: salted hashes are a thing you keep on the end of the connection that is verifying the auth, not on the side that is submitting it.

Comment: @Celada - it's fine. the vote doesn't matter - there's a better answer here anyway. That's what's important. You should reconsider your answer though - it's dangerous. You're right about the hashed client cred of course - for some reason i had the impression that the request was for the reverse op.

Comment: Right, I did edit my answer. I hope it's less dangerous than before.

Comment: @Celada - indeed! I so emphatically *(as I thought)* argued against your answer with JennyD here, and posted this one specifically because there was no warning at all. It's not wrong to say *you can do this thing, but God help you if you do!* where it is quite often wrong to say only *you can do this thing.* I didn't come here and downvote anybody - I just considered it important there be a *strongly* dissenting voice among those heard here.