# Manually enter password into expect and use as variable while scrip is running

Tags: password, variable, expect

I have an expect script that uses interact every time a password is needed. The program that expect is automating asks for the password multiple times. 
Is there a way to only have to type the password once and then have expect use it next time the password is asked for?
Is there a secure way to do this? I don't want the password saved in a file on the computer as this is not secure.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/681928/7552 -- then, you'll replace the interact calls with appropriate expect/send commands.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of securely storing the password, you could use `openssl` to generate an MD5 hash of the password, and then compare subsequent inputs against it. This is similar to how `/etc/passwd` stores passwords:

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt j7bJUIHI YOURSECRETPASSWORD
```

The command will give you a string which you can store in the expect script. When a user inputs the password you'd use

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt j7bJUIHI $INPUT
```

and compare against the stored string. If they match, then $INPUT was the correct password. The `-salt` string can be anything, but it needs to be fixed between invocations of `openssl` to do the comparison correctly.

If you need to retrieve the original password, you can't use this method. Have a look at this entry for a more general discussion on that topic: [Hiding Password in Shell Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/hiding-password-in-shell-scripts)

---

Sorry, reading this a second time I can see I misunderstood your question. Have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681928/how-can-i-make-an-expect-script-prompt-for-a-password. It looks like the solution you're after.